# Remove previously generated .dtb files on the BeagleBone ai

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I'm trying to remove previously generated .dtb files on the BeagleBone-ai the name of my old file is "am5729-beagleboneai-custom.dtb"
I did
1) `sudo rm /boot/dtbs/am5729-beagleboneai-custom.dtb`
2) copied my new generated .dtb file "am5729-custom.dtb" to /boot/dtbs
3) ls /boot/dtbs  to check if my new file is existed and it was there
4) Edit my /boot/uEnv.txt to #dtb=am5729-custom.dtb
5) reboot 
6) after rebooting, I did "show-pins" and still seeing the old results for my "am5729-beagleboneai-custom.dtb"
I'm not sure what should I do to stop getting the results from my old '.dtb' file.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom .dtb then you should uncomment the dtb entry in uEnv.txt

Ex:

```
  dtb=am5729-custom.dtb
```

NOTE: No "#" at the beginning of the line

Also, you should see a kernel version listed under your '/boot/dtbs' folder that matches the output of 'uname -r'.

```
ls /boot/dtbs/
4.14.108-ti-r131
```

You could put your custom .dtb there or comment out the 'uname_r' entry in 'uEnv.txt' and choose another path under dtbs.

Ex:

```
#uname_r=4.14.108-ti-r131
```

This link may be of some assistance to you:
 https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:U-boot_partitioning_layout_2.0

Cheers